# Knockout: Update item in an observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to update an object which is in an observableArray, like this:

```
var vm = {
    tests: ko.observableArray([{input: 'bar'}])
};

vm.tests.push(ko.observable({input: 'foo'}));

ko.applyBindings(vm); 

setTimeout(function () {
    vm.tests()[1]().input = '123';
}, 500);
```

For some reason the change applied in the `setTimeout` does not reflect in the DOM. Any suggestions why? And, is there a way with `knockout` to watch an array and also the values it contains ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23356/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the item's input property an observable too : `{input: ko.observable("foo")}` and then update it with the setter `vm.tests()[1]().input("123")`:

```
var vm = {
    tests: ko.observableArray([{input: 'bar'}])
};

vm.tests.push(ko.observable({input: ko.observable('foo')}));

ko.applyBindings(vm); 

setTimeout(function () {
    vm.tests()[1]().input('123');
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9h21qbve/